# C/C++ Add socket to fd_set when select is pending

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, select, addition

I'm working on a windows/unix multithreaded server application network layer with Berkeley sockets and stumbled upon a problem:

- I have one thread waiting at select with given fd sets.
- From another thread, I need to add a socket to one of the fd sets.
- As the select is currently pending, it cannot be done and leads to a starvation.

Possible solution is to add a timeout to the select. I have seen that on sites addressing networking with select (dated 15 years back).

The question is:
Are there any other solutions? Waiting for timeout still leads to some level of starvation and takes CPU time from the select-waiter thread. I thought it would be possible to redesign the application but adding sockets is also done from threads that select-waiter thread has (and most definitely should have) no idea about, so the condition cannot be avoided.

If not, what sort of timeout should be chosen to achieve best performance / service quality?

Also note that I do realize that it would be better idea to use more advanced API (iocp, kqueue, ...) or a lib that would do it for me, but that is not an option for me at the given point.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an additional socket pair and add one of these sockets to every `select`. To interrupt a running `select`, send a message to it via the other socket.

On the Unix side only, one can send any signal (e.g. `SIGUSR1`) to the waiting thread with `pthread_kill`. `select` with then return a negative value, and `errno` will be set to `EINTR`. But there is nothing like that on the Windows side.

Comment: @Chnossos You can't select a pipe on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I should have specified the OS target.